# Why is AbstractControl root property self referencing in Nativescript?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-directive, nativescript-angular

I'm currently writing a Nativescript angular based application. One of the requirements is a change password function where the user enters a new password in field A and then needs to confirm the password in field B. Doing this in angular with a directive was an easy task but when I use this same directive in my Nativescript application, it does not work.

The problem seems that the root value of the AbstractControl is always referencing to the control itself, what makes it impossible to get/find the other control.

A simplified version of my directive just to show the problem:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[validateEqual]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => EqualValidator),
            multi: true
        }]
})
export class EqualValidator implements Validator {

    constructor(@Attribute('validateEqual') public validateEqual: string) {}

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null  {

        let v = control.value;
        let otherControl = control.root.get(this.validateEqual);
        console.log("other control:", otherControl); 

        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Isn't cross-field validation typically done with a form group at a level that contains both fields?

Comment: Do you have an example for that or is there any documentation about it? As far as I know form validation in angular is always done with a directive on control level.